# JSoup not showing all the data

Tags: java, jsoup

Here is my jsoup code:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.aliexpress.com/category/200214036/women-watches.html?spm=2114.search0103.3.7.765d221bi3J3Io&site=glo&g=y").get();


Elements titleElement = document.select("div.item > div.img > div.pic > a.picRind > img");

String essay = essayElement.text();

int i = 0;
String linkss[] = new String[titleElement.size()];
for(Element el : titleElement){
    linkss[i] = el.attr("abs:src");
    System.out.println(linkss[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Here are 48 results.

`linkss.size()` shows 48

But when I print all images src it prints only 6 and other shows blank. It takes spaces though.

What is the procedure of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By printing all the img elements i just found out that the source attribute for the first six img tags is "src" but for the rest "image-src". In order to get all of them do something like bekow:

```
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.aliexpress.com/category/200214036/women-watches.html?spm=2114.search0103.3.7.765d221bi3J3Io&site=glo&g=y").get();
    Elements titleElement = document.select("div.item > div.img > div.pic > a.picRind > img");
    //print img elements to see if source attribute is "src" or "image-src"
    titleElement.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    //String essay = essayElement.text();
    int i = 0;
    String linkss[] = new String[titleElement.size()];
    for(Element el : titleElement){
        //check if src value is empty, which is true if the src attr does not exist
        if(!el.attr("abs:src").isEmpty()){
            linkss[i] = el.attr("abs:src");
        }
        else{
            linkss[i] = el.attr("abs:image-src");
        }
        //System.out.println(linkss[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I am facing another problem though. Should I ask another question? Or you will help me here?

Comment: Please see this:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48355443/why-jsoup-printing-half-of-all-results