# Why printing half of all results

Tags: java, jsoup

Here is my jsoup code:

```
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    if (!imageElement.get(i).attr("abs:src").isEmpty()) {
        imagesSource[i] = imageElement.get(i).attr("abs:src");
        titlesSource[i] = titleElement.get(i).attr("title");
        System.out.println(imagesSource[i]);
        System.out.println(titlesSource[i]);
    } else {
        imagesSource[i] = imageElement.get(i).attr("abs:image-src");
        titlesSource[i] = titleElement.get(i).attr("title");
        System.out.println(imagesSource[i]);
        System.out.println(titlesSource[i]);

    }
    i++;
}
```

Now there are 48 images and 48 titles. I should get 96 after printing. However, I got 48 only in printing.

When I only print title, I got 48. However, when I print both titles and images I should get 96 lines printed, but I only get 48.

Why?

Comment: your for loop is not right look at @davidxxx answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a jsoup issue.
Your loop increments `i` by `2` :

```
for(i=0; i < j; i++){
  ...
  i++;
}
```

So you skip one element on two.
Remove the  `i++;` .

Generally speaking, it is never a good idea to increment the variable used in the loop initializer outside of the loop increment expression.

Comment: Thanks. Dunno how have I missed it!

Comment: You are welcome :) Debuggers can help you to spot this kind of issue.

Comment: oh yes, next time will follow this.